# Map<dynamic, dynamic> returns null even though data is present

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a map which contains data. But the moment I do this map["content"] it tells me null. What is the problem.

`This is the code`
`final messages = snap.data!.snapshot.value as Map<dynamic, dynamic>;`
`This is what I'm doing`
`messages["idFrom"]`

Comment: Need more context. How is your data structured?

Comment: msg {1673561668839422: {timeStamp: 1673561668840253, idTo: hMKNXQxOHTSi6WqbuHN5uabQwea2, idFrom: 7BEeF0rHihfIFRvv9ClqIdAzzPP2, type: 0, content: Hi}, 1673562395023337: {timeStamp: 1673562395023396, idTo: hMKNXQxOHTSi6WqbuHN5uabQwea2, idFrom: 7BEeF0rHihfIFRvv9ClqIdAzzPP2, type: 0, content: How are you }, 1673562386212261: {timeStamp: 1673562386212326, idTo: hMKNXQxOHTSi6WqbuHN5uabQwea2, idFrom: 7BEeF0rHihfIFRvv9ClqIdAzzPP2, type: 0, content: Hello}, 1673565542635759: {timeStamp: 1673565542636907, idTo: 7BEeF0rHihfIFRvv9ClqIdAzzPP2, idFrom: hMKNXQxOHTSi6WqbuHN5uabQwea2, type: 0, content: Hi}}

Comment: This is the structure when it is printed

Answer (score 0):

messages is `Map<dynamic, dynamic>`  or `Map<int, dynamic>` from your response

```
Map<int, dynamic> messages = {
  1673561668839422: {
    'timeStamp': 1673561668840253,
    'idTo': 'hMKNXQxOHTSi6WqbuHN5uabQwea2',
    'idFrom': '7BEeF0rHihfIFRvv9ClqIdAzzPP2',
    'type': 0,
    'content': 'Hi'
  },
  1673562395023337: {
    'timeStamp': 1673562395023396,
    'idTo': 'hMKNXQxOHTSi6WqbuHN5uabQwea2',
    'idFrom': '7BEeF0rHihfIFRvv9ClqIdAzzPP2',
    'type': 0,
    'content': 'How are you'
  },
  ...
};
```

You cannot do `messages['idFrom']` because `idFrom` is a key from nested `Map` which is :

```
 {
    'timeStamp': 1673561668840253,
    'idTo': 'hMKNXQxOHTSi6WqbuHN5uabQwea2',
    'idFrom': '7BEeF0rHihfIFRvv9ClqIdAzzPP2',
    'type': 0,
    'content': 'Hi'
  }
```

If you wanna access `idFrom` you can either do `messages[int]['idFrom']` where `int` is one of the keys of messages `Map`.

ex.. `print(messages[1673561668839422]['idFrom'])`

> 7BEeF0rHihfIFRvv9ClqIdAzzPP2

Comment: Ok. That shows. But it is a chat app and I tried messages[index-1]["idFrom"], it shows null. @Soliev

Comment: This is the response The method '[]' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: []("idFrom")

Comment: Its a chat app and i want to delete message but Firebase Firestore doesn't allow deletion of sub collections so I used real-time database and I keep getting this error

Comment: Make sure messages is `Map<int,dynamic>`

Comment: what do you suggest?

Comment: This happens [type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<Object?, Object?>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<int, dynamic>']